# Many to many relation hookup in Delphi

Tags: database, delphi

How do I do a many to many  (master-master) relation in Delphi, I cannot find an example. Only dblookups and master-detail which I understand.

Like a product can belong to one or more categories. Like this table structure:

**Product Table**

ProductId, ProductName

**CategoryTable**

CategoryId, CategoryName

**Relation table**

ProductId, CategoryId

Ideally if you select a record in the product grid the edit of a product in a detail record is started in the right side of the screen. In here you can edit the product properties an ideally you can select via checkboxes one or more categories in a checkbox group/grid.

How do you hook this up with TTable of TQuery components? Is there a way?

Hope you can help!

Sincerely Edward

> Some more explaination:
>
> The goal is like:

```
master [product grid list]    Detail [on selected product]
                              property **A**
                              property **B**
                              property **C**
                              property **D**
                              property **Category collection**
                                       Category 1 - checked
                                       Category 2 - unchecked
                                       Category 3 - unchecked
                                       Category 4 - checked
```

Comment: you mean that you want to do this without any code?? just using Object Inspector property?

Comment: only if it is possible. It is not necessary.

Comment: if it is not necessary, you can do it using a detail Grid with a lookup Column for all Categories, that   you can add new record to relation Table using this lookup. if you need more details , let me know, i will code it and send it here as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be transformed to a simple Master-Detail relation by using a joined query over Relation Table and Category Table (similar like this example):

```
SELECT * FROM Relation a
JOIN Category b on a.CategoryId = b.CategoryId
WHERE ProductId = :ProductId
```

In case you want a list of all categories where a separate field indicates if a relation to the product exists, you can use a query like this (example for MSSQL, the new field is named *Checked*):

```
SELECT c.*, CASE WHEN r.CategoryId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Checked
FROM CATEGORY
LEFT JOIN Relation r ON (c.CategoryId = r.CategoryId) AND (r.ProductId = :ProductId)
ORDER BY c.CategoryId
```

Note that you have to write the code to add or delete the relation record when you manipulate the check list by yourself.

Comment: The problem is here that it only returns the catagories which are on the product. I need all the categories to show.   I will elaborate my question more.

Comment: I think you are right. There is I think no way around it to add some coding. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit suprised that there is'nt a component in the rich Delphi toolbox for a problem like this.